# Issues with importing existing source C++ code in Eclipse CDT

Tags: compiling, eclipse, c++, make

I have cloned an emulator's source code from git, and would like to work on it on Eclipse CDT on my Ubuntu 12.04. I have tried different ways, such as creating a hello world project, and simply copy/paste my codes in this project, or using the import option from Eclipse, but none of them work as it should. For the later option, the source code does not recognize even the default include headers, and in the first one I have problem building/running the code given its makefile. Can someone tell me the correct way to import existing source codes with built-in makefile?

The source code folder has already a makefile inside, which nicely builds on terminal. It creates a few executables (Y1, Y2, ...Y6), which each need proper arguments to run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install the GNU C++ compiler from the default Ubuntu repositories (*g++*). The *build-essential* package contains some additional developer tools.

Open Eclipse and select: *Help* -> *C/C++ Development User Guide* -> *Getting Started* -> *Creating a simple application*. This is a complete C++ "Hello world" tutorial including screenshots. Save the "Hello world" project when you are finished. You will need it for your next tutorial: *Help* -> *C/C++ Development User Guide* -> *Getting Started* -> *Creating a Makefile project* and the next tutorial after that: *Importing your C/C++ source files into Eclipse*.